# Unsatisfied Link Error when using System.loadLibrary()?

Tags: java

For some reason, I'm getting a pesky Unsatisfied Link Error in my java app.

This is the offender in question:

```
System.loadLibrary("psjw");
```

Despite the library psjw.dll clearly being in the same source package as this class.

Please help.

Comment: You might consider using System.load(). It takes a fully qualified path, and ignores all the environmental variables. It's just:
`System.load("C:\\Program Files\\My Great Program\\libs\\psjw.dll");`

Note that you can create the string with the path at run time, so you can query first for things like the user's directory, the directory where your program is installed, and so on. This might be preferable to loadLibrary(), since you never know if something on the list of places that searches already has the name "psjw.dll," which could end up loading a library you didn't know was there.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, really good for finding out the root cause of a problem with a library

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the psjw.dll is either on your PATH or java.library.path.

Ex: psjw.dll may be in /usr/lib then your command would be
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib ur.package.UrClass

Test your setup using a stripped down class:

```
public class TestLoadLibrary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String libPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        System.out.println("java.library.path=" + libPath);

        String libraryName = "psjw";
        System.out.println("Trying to load '" + libraryName + "'");
        System.loadLibrary(libraryName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I understand that the DLL must be in the classpath to reference, and it is. Shouldn't the .jar classpath by default be set to the .jar? Because compiling it and executing the .jar is no help.

Comment: The DLL must be in the PATH of the process attempting to load the DLL into memory. Java uses CLASSPATH to find classes. The operating system's loader uses PATH (on Windows) to find DLLs you're trying to load dynamically.

Comment: @Aaron - Like Brian said, there are two different things at work here.  CLASSPATH is completely separate from PATH or java.library.path.  CLASSPATH points to jars/classes, PATH or java.library.path to locations of executables/dlls.

Comment: Yes, and the PATH on my system is set to a folder in my documents. The DLL is in the folder. Still getting the exception.

Comment: Going to need the exact exception then as there are multiple types of Unsatisfied Link Errors.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set explicity the library path when starting the JVM: `-Djava.library.path="Directory of DLL"`

Answer (score 3):

For correct lookup of library (from *java.library.path*) for different OS's must have different names:

- Linux: *libpsjw.so*
- Windows: *psjw.dll*

Than you can call from Java:

```
System.loadLibrary( "psjw" );
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can say from my experience is that, if the loadLib(libraryName) is performed from static initialization block in java class file, the libraray should be exists in java.library.path. Otherwise class cannot be loaded. But if we are moving the loadLibrary() call to under other methods e.g Main(), it can be read from environment path.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this same issue for two days, but I eventually found the answer.  First I created a directory for libraries, and set the PATH environment variable to that directory.  I don't like clogging up my path though, so now I give you what I found at http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/.  My rendition follows

```
package yourpackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field ;

public class YourClass {
    public native void print () ;
    static
    {
        String mPath = new File (".").getAbsolutePath () ;
        String langKey = "java.library.path" ;
        System.setProperty ( langKey, mPath ) ;

        // Tested both with and without the following, and worked either way.
/*      try
        {
            Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
            fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
            fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
        }
        catch ( NoSuchFieldException e )
        {
            System.err.println ( "Unable to reset system path field: \n" + e + '\n' ) ;
        }
        catch ( IllegalAccessException e )
        {
            System.err.println ( "Unable to access system path after reset: \n"
                    + e + '\n' ) ;
        } */

        try
        {
            System.loadLibrary ( "YourLibrary" ) ;
        }
        catch ( UnsatisfiedLinkError e )
        {
            System.err.println ( "Native code library failed to load.\n" + e ) ;
            System.exit ( 1 ) ; 
        }

    }

    public static void main ( String[] args)
    {
        YourClass yc = new YourClass() ;
        yc.print();
    }
}
```

For the above code your dll needs to be in the same folder as your .java.  If you are running from command line, remember you call from the same directory for javac, and root package directory for java calling.  Thus for the .java being C:\workspace\yourpackage\YourClass.java, you call from command line :

```
cd "C:\workspace"
java yourpackage.YourClass
```