# UnsatisfiedLinkError: className.methodName - JNI on WebLogic

Tags: java-native-interface, weblogic

A web app deployed to WebLogic calls native methods in a SomeProxy.class. This SomeProxy.class is deployed as shared library. It has a static block to load native library.

```
public class SomeProxy {
    static { 
        System.load("/path/to/jnilib"); 
        setup();
    }
    public static native void setup();
    public native int solve();
}
```

A client class in web app has the following code to invoke SomeProxy.class.

```
public class SomeClient {

    void use() {
        SomeProxy proxy = new SomeProxy();
        int result = proxy.solve();
    }
}
```

The first deployment of the web app runs successfully. The web app was then stopped, deleted, and reinstalled. The invocation of the native method failed, and gave the following error message.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: package/name/SomeProxy.setup()V
at package.name.SomeProxy.<clinit>(SomeProxy.java:19)
at package.name.SomeClient.use(SomeClient.java:112)
```

Comment: What is your java.library.path set to for access to the native library?

Comment: "java.library.path" does not come into play. Class SomeProxy uses System.load(), not System.loadLibrary(). Also, the first deployment succeeded.

Comment: I'd still give it a go just to see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071975/unsatisfied-link-error-when-using-system-loadlibrary